# Shortening of formulas (from using IF, MAX)

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

Is there a way to shorten any of these these formulas? Processing them seems to take a very long time (up to 15 minutes) given the time needed to recalculate the data.

This  [link provided](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0g80ea9brh252hl/Stackoverflow.xlsx) is for the file. The headings in the file are for the respective formulas below.

```
latest 24 mth data =IF(C4>=EDATE(MAX($C$4:$C$1048576),-23),"Latest Months","Consol. Years")

Past 7 Years =IF(D4>=MAX($D$4:$D$1048576)-7,"Past 7 years","")

Latest Season =IF(AND(MONTH(MAX($C$4:$C$1048576))>=4,MONTH(MAX($C$4:$C$1048576))<=10),IF(AND(D4=MAX($D$4:$D$1048576)-5,E9="W"),"Latest Seasons",IF(D4>=MAX($D$4:$D$1048576)-4,"Latest Seasons","")),IF(D4>=MAX($D$4:$D$1048576)-4,"Latest Seasons",""))

Latest Year =IF(D4>=MAX($D$4:$D$1048576)-4,"Latest yrs","")
```

Comment: As we can't really audit a formula without the data for us, I suggest two things: provide a file with the above formulas and similar dummy data, or tell us exactly what the above are for. I'm seeing too many references to the bottom row of Excel 2010 (1048576). I will say outright that this is not necessary unless you have data until that row.

Comment: Pardon me, but how would I upload a file?

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant, upload a file somewhere and provide the link here. :)

Comment: Thanks alot! I have uploaded the link to the file and made a few adjustments to the formulas. Please take a look!

Comment: Well, for one thing, you could make a reference cell somewhere to contain the calculation for `MAX($D$4:$D$1048576)` and `MAX($C$4:$C$1048576)`. Those would thus be calculated only once and shorten all your formulae by quite some characters.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see here is that your range is way too large. Your formulas are evaluating 900,000 more cells than they need to determine the max date. You can set the range as $C$$:$C$150000, which would cut down on the processing time.

If your range keeps expanding, consider making a named range that expands by going to the name manager and typing in something like: =OFFSET(Sheet1!$C4,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$C$4:$C$150000),1)

Another option is to get the max date in one cell, then just keep referring to the value of that cell in the rest of your formulas.